# Facebook access_token for ads

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk

I have ad campaign and want to receive stats for it with this facebook [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group). 
But everywhere I see access_token required. And I don't understand where I can find it for me as developer for ad.

I've used [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/223087108146405) for user access token, and I see there app token and page token. But no access token for ad. 
So my questions:
1. Is it possible to get data from ad campaign as developer?
2. How can I generate access_token for developer for ad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps you need to follow to get started:

1. Visit https://developers.facebook.com and create your app if you haven't already
2. Visit the Marketing API > Tools page (put your APP ID in): 
   `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_ID>/marketing-api/tools/`
3. Create a sandbox ad account and generate a sandbox token to test with (see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOyMF.jpg)

Once you're ready to go live you'll need to then:

4. Visit the Marketing API > Settings page (put your APP ID in): `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_ID>/marketing-api/settings/`
5. Link your ad account
6. Go back to the Marketing API > Tools page and generate a real access token

Comment: But what if I have ads, but doesn't have app? I mean I have three sites, and ads for this three sites. But I have no apps for this sites. Does it mean that I can create one app to manage unlimited number of ads?

Comment: You can assign multiple ad accounts to one app or have separate apps for each. The choice is yours.